# Search for field presence of type String in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

We recently changed the type of a field "foo_duration" from type string to numeric. I would like to re-index all the indices that contain the documents with the field of type string.

Is there a way to query for index names that contain documents with the "foo_duration" field present and of type string?